# VBA Autofilter criteria: apply if ALL cells in current range/row is blank

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

How do I apply an autofilter criteria that only applies if EVERY cell in range, let's say a row of 10 cells, are blank.

I tried the approach below but the autofilter isn't applied this way.

```
With range
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5:J5")) = 0
End with
```

The aim is to hide rows within the range in which all the cells are blank. It's required that ALL the cells are blank, not just 9/10 or 1/10 for example.

I'm surprised I wasn't able to find a similar question anywhere and I'm wondering whether my search is simply wrong - but that doesn't change the fact that I can't find similar questions or answers. So in advance, sorry if this already has been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stack 10 fields of filtering. One does not overwrite the other, each augments the previous filter set.

To hide rows where columns 1-10 are blank,

```
With range
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
     .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
End with
```

To expose rows where columns 1-10 are blank for deletion or other operation,

```
With range
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="="
     .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="="
End with
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind using a "helper" column you could avoid `AutoFilter()`:

```
With myRange
    With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1) ' enlarge referenced range by one "helper" column and reference this latter
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTA(RC1:RC[-1])=0,1, """")" ' fill referenced "helper" range with a formula outputting a number if condition is met
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide referenced range rows with a numeric value
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(, 1).ClearContents ' clear helper column formula
    End With
End With
```

in this example the "helper" column is just one column right of referenced range

but the code could be tweaked to use whatever "helper" column